# Update the background image with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

In jQuery, I'm trying to change the background image of a div:

```
var USR_Settings_Color = $('.social-icons ul li a.active').css('background-image');
// Return : url("https://example.com/fir-DIY.jpg")
```

After I update the  like this:

```
$('#preview').html('<div style="background-image: '+USR_Settings_Color+'"></div>');
```

But the result is like this:

```
<div style="background-image:url(" https:="" example.com="" fir-diy.jpg");="" background-clip:="" text;="" -webkit-background-clip:="" color:="" transparent;"=""></div>
```

I think it's a conflict with the `'` and `"`.

How I can solve this please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use Html attr instead of css?
try do this instead:

```
$('#preview').css('background-image', USR_Settings_Color)
```

by the way I would take all the properties you added in the html attribute, and put them in class, by this you just adding the specific div the class to keep a cleaner code.

Comment: I can't make this as the `.html()` is building my code.

Comment: @Maman unless you have a bizarre requirement to only use `.html()` then you can still do `var newElement = $('#preview').html('<div>").css('background-image', USR_Settings_Color)`

Answer (score 0):

try use the backtag instead:

```
$('#preview').html(`<div style=background-image:${USR_Settings_Color}></div>`);
```